# Circuit breaker wiring: put source current on side marked with X or side with switch?

Tags: schematics, wiring, automation, circuit-breaker

I am trying to wire an electrical panel in a standard manner.

I have several automation devices that take 120 Vac power.  In order to protect them, I have purchased a 2-pole circuit breaker, [Phoenix Contact TMC 72B 10A](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/online/portal/us?uri=pxc-oc-itemdetail:pid=1019938).  I am now trying to wire it to an outlet.  I plan to put the breaker on `L` and `N` of the 120 Vac source.

The circuit breaker's schematic is shown in the below image.  Pins 1 + 3 connect to an `X`, pins 2 + 4 connect to what looks like a SPST switch.

**Questions**

- What do the X's mean?
- Where should I put power inlet?  On pins 1 + 3, or pins 2 + 4?

Any additional advice is welcome, I am looking to comply with industry standards.  Thank you in advance for your help!

[image: TMC 72B 10A Top Image]

Comment: This question needs to go to the https://diy.stackexchange.com, or an industrial stackexchange, if there is such a thing. This is the *electronics* engineering stackexchange, which means we (mostly) work with itty bitty clean things.  Industrial wiring is a great big dirty thing, and while we know the principles, most of us don't have experience with the practicalities (although a very few of us do).

Comment: *" I am looking to comply with industry standards"* Where I live, you can only comply with industry standards if you have a certificate to wire electrical panels.

Comment: The 'X'-looking marks are the circuit breakers.

Comment: @Oldfart if it were a *home* automation project then in some jurisdictions in the US the homeowner could do the work -- but they'd need to get it inspected (and likely critiqued) if they wanted to be legal.

Comment: 'IN' is at the 'Top' of the breaker, on the terminals marked '1' & '3'.

Comment: @brhans thank you for answering my question, any chance you could just explain why `1` and `3` are the inlet vs the bottom?

Comment: @C.Lange thank you for pointing out that answer, I found the answer there quite useful!

Comment: All of the 'standard' DIN-rail breakers I've ever seen have 'IN' at the 'Top' of the breaker. There are very few with 'IN' at the 'Bottom', and these are intended for very specific purposes.

Comment: @TimWescott yeah sorry about wrong space, sometimes lines are blurred for me

Comment: Generally, simple breakers like this can be back-fed with no trouble.  This is AC power, after all, and it's not doing anything special like GFCI.   So it doesn't matter.  Supply hot+neutral can go to 1+3, or 2+4, your call.